# Trying to access parent from child class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I've a product class that I populate using (PDO::FETCH CLASS, 'Product') 
and then echo each item to the page.  There are a lot of items per category.  This is being used my my "display items by category" page.

```
 class Product {

// All attributes correspond to database columns.
// All attributes are protected.
protected $productID = null;
protected $name = null;
protected $description = null;
protected $price = null;
protected $image = null;

// Method returns the product ID:
function getProductID() {
    return $this->productID;
}    

// and other methods to return each variable 
 }
```

You then click on the link that passes the productID, using MVC model, to display the product details page which I want to display the one item in greater detail.  The information from the above product class and the child class i've created below.

I've then extended this class to a Stock class which contains all the options for each product. That is, the size, colour, qty.  For example... one T-Shirt can have 3 different sizes, 2 different colours and each of these variations can have a quantity.

I populate the Stock class using a PDO::FETCH CLASS method as well.

The extended class is:

```
 class Stock extends Product{

// All attributes correspond to database columns.
// All attributes are protected.
protected $productID = null;
protected $qty = null;
protected $colour = null;
protected $colourHEX = null;
protected $sizeName = null;

// Method returns the product ID:
function getproductID() {
    return $this->productID;
}

// Method returns the product ID:
function getQty() {
    return $this->qty;
}
```

My problem is that I have created both of these classes seperately on seperate webpages and I don't know how to access the parent class from the child. I've been trying to understand this all day.  I know that I haven't created an association between the stock child class and the parent but cannot think how to do this so I can access the parents methods to display the name, price, etc..

Have I included enough information?

I'm really really struggling

Comment: I must be missing something - you extended the 'product' class with your 'stock' class. So why can't you just call the 'public' member functions in the parent class? Inheritance gives you those by design.

Comment: Why does stock inherit from product? You might 1. try using composition and 2. you could add a reference to the stock and populate/access the stock via setter/getter.